# Capturar conteúdo digitado TOASTUi Editor

Tags: javascript, markdown

Estou criando uma aplicação para inserção de informações com o TOASTUI - EDITOR

[TOASTui Editor](https://ui.toast.com/tui-editor)

Eu consigo ao abrir um modal criar a tela de edição e inserir os dados que ja possuo no banco para possível alteração, porem após a alteração por alguém, eu preciso capturar esses dados e gravar no banco, que faço ao clicar no botão submit, porem os dados não são capturados como os input normais (tenho 1 nessa tela), tenho 4 div TOASTui Editor com id e nomes diferente, e um input tipo texto

```
<input name="DESCRICAO" id="DESCRICAO" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Exemplo">
```

demais entradas são criadas dessa forma

```
<div id="REQUISITOS" name="REQUISITOS">

<script>
     const REQUISITOS = new toastui.Editor({
                    el: document.querySelector('#REQUISITOS'),
                    previewStyle: 'tab',
                    initialEditType: 'wysiwyg',
                    initialValue: resREQUISITOS,
                });
</script>
```

A tela abre e carrega os dados conforme o esperado, porem ao capturar com:

```
const data = new FormData(event.target);
const value = Object.fromEntries(data.entries(null));
```

que me retorna apenas o campo input

```
{
    "DESCRICAO": "TESTE HTML"
}
```

de acordo com a documentação da API eu deveria recuperar os dados com getMarkdown():

```
const OBSERVACAO = new toastui.Editor({
                    el: document.querySelector('#OBSERVACAO'),
                    previewStyle: 'tab',
                    initialEditType: 'wysiwyg',
                    initialValue: resOBSERVACAO,
                });

OBSERVACAO.getMarkdown();
```

que funciona perfeitamente no momento em que carregado os dados e ja recupero o conteudo, porem ao gravar esse comando não funciona

```
getMarkdown is not a function
```

se eu criar novamente quando clicar botão submit:

```
   var editor = new toastui.Editor({
        el: document.querySelector('#OBSERVACAO')
    });
    console.log(editor.getMarkdown());
```

Os dados capturados vem desta forma:

```
Write
Preview
Insert codeBlock
\<ul>\<li>Hello World\</li>\<li>Click the button below to show this text code\</li>\</ul>

* Hello World
* Click the button below to show this text code


* Hello World
* Click the button below to show this text code

Markdown
WYSIWYG
```

porem os dados digitados, ou ja salvos são:

```
\<ul>\<li>Hello World\</li>\<li>Click the button below to show this text code\</li>\</ul>
    
    * Hello World
    * Click the button below to show this text code
    
    
    * Hello World
    * Click the button below to show this text code
```

Resumindo: Preciso capturar os dados dentro TOASTUi-Editor em Javascript apos clicar em salvar e não no momento que instancio o objeto

Answer (score -1):

Creio que muitos aqui sabem o motivo, recebi votos negativos por eu não saber me explicar bem ou por não saber resolver algo simples, faltou um pouco mais de conhecimento minha parte, que eu esperava conseguir aqui, problema simples e resolvi colocando a variável inicial como Glabal ai consegui chamar em outros locais